# Ошибка при установке miniconda или anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda, conda

При установке miniconda или anaconda на Ubuntu16 после:

> ./Anaconda3-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh

следующая ошибка (какие есть решения?):

> PREFIX=/home/miniconda
>   Unpacking payload ...
>   [13315] Error loading Python lib '/tmp/_MEIFpKyJI/libpython3.6m.so.1.0': dlopen: /tmp/_MEIFpKyJI/libpython3.6m.so.1.0: failed to map segment from shared object
>   ERROR: could not extract tar starting at offset 000000000000018891+9231072+2

Comment: Извините, а зачем вам анаконда в убунту?

Comment: Интересный вопрос, а почему ее не может быть на ubuntu и где(на чем) она тогда должна быть?